# Dart: How to work around the diamond pattern with mixins?

Tags: dart, mixins

Is there a way to solve the diamond problem when using Mixins in Dart?
Have a look on the following simple example:

```dart
class M1 {
  String sayHello() => "hello M1";
}
class M2 {
  String sayHello() => "hello M2";
}
class S {
  String sayHello() => "hello S";
}
class C extends S with M1, M2 {}

main() {
  C c = new C();
  print(c.sayHello());
  print((c as M1).sayHello());
}
```

Output:

```dart
hello M2
hello M2
```

If you call "sayHello" on c, it depends on the order of the mixins in the class declaration of 
C, which of the implementations is executed. Always the implementation of the last mixin on the list is used. This is hardly explicit and might often be a matter of chance. Worse: The implementation of the superclass C is always hidden.
The typecast doesn't change a thing, which of course is in accord with the general Dart philosophy that the runtime type doesn't come into play when executing code. Still it would be good if there were any means to explicitly decide between the different implementations. Is there such a possibility?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. This also applies for normal inheritance. I think the order of Mixins is explicit though, it is the same as the order of normal inheritance. For normal inheritance you can use `super` which is not **yet** available for Mixins. I think this is the main problem. The Dart team is aware of the limitations of Mixins and there are plans to remove them but as always, they provide no information when this will land.

Comment: The situation is different to "normal" inheritance as multiple inheritance is not possible in Dart, is it? The problem I see is, that I cannot explicitly choose between the different implementations of "sayHello" at the location where the function is called. This is differently solved in C++, where it is possible to qualify the function call with the name of the declaring class (if I remember my old C++ days correctly).

Comment: No, it isn't.
What I tried to explain was, that `(new M2() as M1).sayHello()` also wouldn't call the `sayHello()` implementation in `M1` but the one in `M2` when using normal inheritance (like `class M1 extends S {}`, `class M2 extends M1 {}`).

Comment: You are right about that the missing super to the mixins worsens the situation, as you cannot resolve the conflict in the child class by explicitly forwarding to the one or the other mixin or the super class.

Comment: Okay, understood. The cast doesn't help to select between the implementation in the parent and child class either. So in this respect the problem arises independent of mixins. But this doesn't make it better :-)

Comment: No it doesn't LOL. 
As mentioned above, thats a know limitation which should be removed. They just tried to get a minimal implementation of Mixins into Dart 1.0 and improve it later.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Hi, I'm from 2019, it's still there.

Answer (score 5):

In short: No.

You can't solve a diamond problem in Dart because Dart doesn't have multiple inheritance, so it doesn't have the problem (or feature).

Adding mixins on top of a class is completely normal single inheritance, and Dart class implementation is always a single chain down to Object.
The only thing mixins do is to allow the same members to occur in more than one chain.

That also means that there is no way to access overridden members higher in the chain.
You can only ever access the top-most declaration, or, as a member function, the top-most declaration of your super-chain (using `super.foo()`).

Comment: I don't understand your "and Dart class implementation is always a single chain down to Object. The only thing mixins do is to allow the same members to occur in more than one chain."